# How to copy an image and add it as its parents background image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to copy the src from an image and add it to its immediate parent background image.

For example, here is my html

```
<div class="win__image">
    <div class="field-item even">
        <img data-original="https://davecross.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/pale-blue-dot.jpg" class="img-responsive" src="https://davecross.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/pale-blue-dot.jpg"
            width="960" height="620" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And, I am trying to do something like below

```
var $winImage = $('.win__image');

if ($winImage.length > 0) {
    $winImage.find('img').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.win__image .field-item').css({
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'background-position': 'center center',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        'width': '960px',
        'height': '620px',
        'background-image': 'url("' + $winImage.find('img').src('data-original') + '")'
    });
}
```

Example link:
http://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/wgMEMp

Now, firstly the image does not get copied. It says "undefined" in the image background url.Also, how to get its immediate parent?

Comment: You must put your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code */});`.

Comment: That is not the problem... That basically says that the code is executed when everything is ready. In my case, it is ready and I am anyway doing that in my real work..

Comment: Yes I tried with both.. Either way it does not work.. May you help me to edit the codepen and see if you can work that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a small error in the way you were getting winImageSrc:

```
var $winImage = $('.win__image');
var $winImageSrc = $winImage.find('img').data('original');
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if ($winImage.length > 0) {
    $winImage.find('img').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.win__image .field-item').css({
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'background-position': 'center center',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        'width': '960px',
        'height': '620px',
        'background-image': 'url("' + $winImageSrc + '")'
    });
}
```

**Edit**: In the first solution I replaced

```
$('.win__image .field-item').css({
```

with

```
$(winImage).parent().css({
```

but then I realized it was not exactly what you wanted to do. Anyway, consider using parent() to get the immediate parent of an element.

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntex issue in your code, you can use below code:

```
var $winImage = $('.win__image');

if ($winImage.length > 0) {
    $winImage.find('img').css('opacity', '0');
    $('.win__image .field-item').css({
        'background-size': 'cover',
        'background-position': 'center center',
        'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
        'width': '960px',
        'height': '620px',
        'background-image': 'url("' + $winImage.find('img').attr('data-original') + '")'
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$winImage.find('img').src('data-original')
```

To this:

```
$winImage.find('img').attr('data-original');
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace only line your code is working...

```
$winImage.find('img').attr('data-original');
```